# using .match() returning 0 of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

```
 var v = $(forum[yourVersion]+' a[href*="youtube.com/v/"]');
   for ( i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
     var match = v[i].href.match(/\(((\s*?.*?)*?)\)/);
     v[i].href = v[i].href.replace(match[0],'');
     var c = v[i].href.replace(/(www\.)?youtube.com/, 'img.youtube.com');
     var d = c.replace('v','vi');
     v[i].outerHTML= '<a class="uTubeE" rel="vid_gallery" title="'+match[1]+'" href="' + v[i].href + '"><span class="uTubeE_overlay"></span><img src="'+ d +'/0.jpg"/>';
     v[i].className='uTubeE';
    }
```

I am trying to get this two work correctly, and earlier someone helped me to remember about `.match()` and doing this -

```
var match = v[i].href.replace(/\(((\s*?.*?)*?)\)/,'');
```

of course that worked, but I need to get it so I can use match[0] and match[1] for later uses such as the title attribute.

Can anyone help with this?

This is to use the default thumbnail of youtube video

```
     var c = v[i].href.replace(/(www\.)?youtube.com/, 'img.youtube.com');
     var d = c.replace('v','vi');
```

The urls I am matching are say `www.youtube.com/v/dje838329` but the url would come up as
`www.youtube.com/v/dje838329(titleOfMovie)`

I am trying to grab the data of (titleOfMovie) to use for later uses.

Instead of saying it WAY wrong, please make some useful comments, such as maybe what is wrong, as it does work just can't use it like I should for later purposes.

Comment: I think you need to break this down into a smaller component. I'm not even sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: It would help a whole lot if you'd post some of the URLs you're trying to match.

Comment: What is that first regex trying to do?  It is way wrong whatever it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your expression `\(((\s*?.*?)*?)\)` and it worked on your sample text `www.youtube.com/v/dje838329(titleOfMovie)`. I did make a couple of small changes to it:

Regex: `\(([^)]*)\)`

- `\(` match the open paran
- `(` start your capture group

  - `[^)]*` match all the non-close paran characters
  - `)` end the capture group
- `\)` match the close paran

[image]

## Javascript Code Example:

**Sample Text**

```
www.youtube.com/v/dje838329(title of the movie)**
```

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var re = /\(([^)]*)\)/;
  var sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  var matches = re.exec(sourcestring);
  for (var i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
    alert("matches["+i+"] = " + matches[i]);
  }
</script>
```

**Capture Groups**

```
[0] => (title of the movie)
[1] => title of the movie
```

## Disclaimer

Of course this will fail to match if the string doesn't have the title in the `(name of the movie)` format

Comment: As I did figure this out later on in my testing and debugging, I had to step out. but what I came up with was something like this, and I changed my old regex to the one you have...

`   var match =\(([^)]*)\).exec(v[i].href);
if(match == null){
 title="";
  continue;
} else {
v[i].href = v[i].href.replace(match[0],'');
title= match[1];
}`

Answer (score 1):

> using `.match()` returning 0 of undefined

That's not the error you're getting. The problem is you are accessing the `0` property of a [match result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) which might be `null` when the regex does not match. You have to test on that before trying to get the results.

> Using `replace` worked, but I need to get it so I can use match[0] and match[1] for later uses

You could try a replacer function, but that's just would get ugly. Your `match` is fine, especially since you're not doing any fancy operations. Just take its matching index and slice your url.

Btw, if you have jQuery available you really should use it.

```
var v = $(forum[yourVersion]+' a[href*="youtube.com/v/"]').each(function() {
    var url = this.href,
        match = url.match(/\(((\s*?.*?)*?)\)/);
    if (match == null)
        return; // abort!
    var d = url.replace(/(www\.)?youtube.com\/v/, 'img.youtube.com/vi');
    this.href = url.slice(0, match.index);
    this.className = "uTubeE"
    this.rel = "vid_gallery";
    this.title = match[1];
    this.innerHTML = '<span class="uTubeE_overlay"></span><img src="'+ d +'/0.jpg"/>';
});
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying now, though I never use the `.each()` ever. I use for loops as it is faster over all and especially if you are doing alot within the `.each()` thank you for your explanation, I appreciate it.

Comment: If you're looking that much for speed you wouldn't use jQuery at all, and especially not with such inefficient selectors. The `each` with callback is fine and the encapsulation helps to write cleaner code. In the loop, you'd had to replace the `this` with `v[i]` and `return` with `continue`. If you like the explanation, don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer.